# How can I create a dummy/binary variable to the next date if there is not exactly the event date?

Tags: r, date, events, dummy-variable

I have the following problem:

I have a panel dataset that is structured as follows:

```
> Symbol    Date    Close.Company   Close.Index   Event
> AAPL  25/05/2021  126900002       13657,1699    14/03/2020
> AAPL  26/05/2021  126849998       13738         14/03/2020
> AAPL  27/05/2021  125279999       13736,2803    14/03/2020
> AAPL  28/05/2021  124610001       13748,7402    14/03/2020
> VISA  02/01/2019  132,919998      6665,93994    12/03/2020
> VISA  03/01/2019  128,130005      6463,5        12/03/2020
> VISA  04/01/2019  133,649994      6738,85986    12/03/2020
> VISA  07/01/2019  136,059998      6823,47022    12/03/2020
```

[image]

Now I am trying to create a dummy variable at the point where the event is at the corresponding company. To do this, I tried the following code to find the date of the event or the next date (if the event is not in the dataset):

```
Kurse_gesamt$EventBin <- ifelse(Kurse_gesamt$Event == Kurse_gesamt$Date | Kurse_gesamt$Date == (Kurse_gesamt$Event+1), 1, 0)
```

I tried this code too, but it returns the same:

```
Kurse_gesamt$EventBin2 <- ifelse(Kurse_gesamt$Event == Kurse_gesamt$Date, 1, (ifelse(Kurse_gesamt$Date == (Kurse_gesamt$Event+1), 1, 0)))
```

It now finds the event of VISA twice, because there is both the event and the following date.  For APPL, unfortunately, it does not find any of the dates. The event is on a Saturday and the next date would be a Sunday:

```
> Symbol    Date    Close.Company   Close.Index Event      EventBin   EventBin2
> VISA  12/03/2020  160,080002      7201,79981  12/03/2020  1            1
> VISA  13/03/2020  175,830002      7874,87988  12/03/2020  1            1
> AAPL  02/01/2019  39480000        6665,93994  14/03/2020  0            0
> AAPL  03/01/2019  35547501        6463,5      14/03/2020  0            0
> AAPL  04/01/2019  37064999        6738,85986  14/03/2020  0            0
```

Is there now a way to tell R that if the event is not in the dataset, it is looking for the next possible date?

To do this, R should output exactly 1 dummy variable for each company for the event. In my dataset it also happens that the next possible date can only be found in the next month.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

Kurse_Gesamt <- as.data.table(Kurse_Gesamt)
Kurse_Gesamt[difftime(Date, Event) >= 0, Eventbin := ifelse(difftime(Date, Event) == min(difftime(Date, Event)), 1, NA), by=.(Symbol)]
```